# Best sql db structure for big phone Directory

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a big db for a phone directory wich contains about 50 Million rows, each row contains two columns "phonenumber" and the second is "names" , the phone number is varchar of 15 characters length, and the "names" column is also varchar with 500 length, the names column contains multiple people names which are separated with ";"

The problem in that database is when i use a select query to search for a number it executes very fast, but when I search for a person name using like "%marlin% it executes very slow, because it is doing a full scan for the table.

How can I redesign my db structure in order to have fast queries when I search for phone number for any one with a specific name like "%martin%"?

ps: I have basic knowledge in MYSQL;

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Multiple names means ? 2 or more 2 people can have same number ?

Comment: Look into using full text search.  Yes, searching by `%martin%` won't be able to use an index on the `names` column, even if it exists.

Comment: multiple names like this : martin; martin sylvie, martin garagel; sylvie

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your database. Currently you have a 'sub-database' in your names-field, and you want that seperate

```
numbers: id, number
persons: id, name
person_numbers: person_id, number_id
```

Now you need to find the name in the `persons` table, and then it's numbers. This might not be much quicker, depending on how many names there are.

Next step might be to add an index to your `persons.name` field

Be advised that this is a quick, really simplified version of waht you need to do be doing, but seeing your question and the current state, you are a beginner. Start reading up on these things, you probably have a lot more steps to go to make this fast. You might even want to consider non-sql solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help